# Typescript get Parameters from a dynamic function

Tags: typescript

I want to get the parameters of a function that is saved in different modules. For example myFunction gets the function I desired, then it should be executed with the correct parameters. However the Parameters line shows the following error: **Type 'Function' does not satisfy the constraint**

```
public Execute(module: any, myFunction: Function, params: string){
     type TestArgsType = Parameters<typeof myFunction>;
     myFunction.apply(module, params);
}
```

Is there any way to use the Parameters with a function passed as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can if you make yours generic.

```
const Execute = <T extends (...args: unknown[]) => unknown>(module: any, myFunction: T, params: string){
     type TestArgsType = Parameters<T>;
```

or

```
const Execute = <TestArgsType extends unknown[]>(module: any, myFunction: (...args: T) => unknown, params: string){
```

You might also consider typing `module` to be something more precise, or at least `unknown` - using `any` defeats the purpose of TypeScript.